# Getting data from plist in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, plist

I want to get data from the plist file of my project which should be sorted. Now my plist looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>code</key>
        <string>AF</string>
        <key>phone_code</key>
        <string>93</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Afghanistan</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>code</key>
        <string>AL</string>
        <key>phone_code</key>
        <string>355</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Albania</string>
    </dict>
```

and so on on upto last country.And I am fetching data like this

```
 NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CountriesWithPhoneCodes" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray* a = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    for (NSDictionary *d in a)
    {
        NSString *cdate = [d objectForKey:@"CDate"];
        if ([cdate isEqualToString:@"Whatever is currently selected"])
        {
            NSString *text = [d objectForKey:@"Text"];
            // do something with text here
        }
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    dict = [self indexKeyedDictionaryFromArray:a];

    NSLog(@"This is %@",[[dict allValues]objectAtIndex:0]);
```

The output I am getting  is

```
This is {
    code = AF;
    name = Afghanistan;
    "phone_code" = 93;
}
```

from which I am unable to access data properly. How can I create a dictionary with phone_code as value and country name as key.

Comment: what you want to access ?  This is {
    code = AF;
    name = Afghanistan;
    "phone_code" = 93;
}

Comment: It's quite unclear. `d` doesn't have a key `"CDate"`. You could use a predicate, or `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` to find which dictionary you want. Also, instead of using an array, if we consider there is unicity for countries name, you could use instead the country name as a key and use a dictionary at top level.

Comment: What do you mean `from which I am unable to access data properly` ? You rather want a dictionary only holding `name ` and `phone_code`?

Comment: I want to made a dictionary of phone_code as value and country name as key

Answer (score 1):

`NSPredicate` perfectly fits your needs.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CountriesWithPhoneCodes" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phone_code = %@", @"String variable containing code"];
NSDictionary *countryDictionary = [array filteredArrayWithPredicate:predicate].firstObject;
```

If you'd like to create dictionary with such struct: `{"phone_code":"country_code"}`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *phonesDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    NSString *phoneCode = dict[@"phone_code"];
    NSString *countryCode = dict[@"country_code"];
    phonesDict[countryCode] = phoneCode;
}
```

Note: you should store this dictionary somewhere to avoid accessing file on disk.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *dictRoot = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"]];

// Your dictionary contains an array of dictionary
// Now pull an Array out of it.
NSArray *arrayList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dictRoot objectForKey:@"catlist"]];

// Now a loop through Array to fetch single Item from catList which is Dictionary
[arrayList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
// Fetch Single Item
// Here obj will return a dictionary
NSLog(@"Category name : %@",[obj valueForKey:@"category_name"]);
NSLog(@"Category id   : %@",[obj valueForKey:@"cid"]);
}];
```